# Android MediaRecorder - Setting the Profile Not Working

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I've looked around but cannot find an answer to my issue. I'm setting the MediaRecorder as follows:

```
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

if(CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P))
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
else
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
```

On my Samsung S3, QUALITY480 is chosen by the code above. A video file is created but it has zero bytes. The same happens if I explicitly set it to QUALITY_LOW. If I set the profile to QUALITY_720P, then I get proper video. Anyone have any ideas? I don't want to set it to 720 so I can keep the file size down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have more code than this bc media recorder is not simple to control see the docs..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Ummm at first look i would say that you are using camera2 api and you are getting true back for your first desired profile but it is not available on device see the has profile doc on android Dev